# Go to another activity when error is thrown by catch() in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

This is my AsyncTask:

```
public class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONArray> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // [...]
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

            int result_length = 0;

            try {
                result_length = result.length();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                // Redirect the user back to the original activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
                // [...]
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // [...]
        }
}
```

When `result` is null, .length() throws a NullPointerException. That's why I want to redirect the url back to MainActivity when this happen.

```
try {
    result_length = result.length();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    // Redirect the user back to the original activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. I get `e.printStackTrace()` but the activity doesn't change. It's like Intent is not "fast" enough to change activity, and the code below (`for (int i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {}`) still keeps running.
What can I do? Is my solution wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think async task is a thread, that's why the `for` loop executes even after facing exception. So you have to cancel your `AsyncTask` as soon as you get error(i.e in `catch` block).

Answer (score 0):

In the AsyncTask contructor provide the Activity reference.

```
private Activity activity;

public GetDataTask (Activity activity) {
   this.activity = activity;
}
```

then you can call it like this

```
activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's like Intent is not "fast" enough to change activity

When you launch an activity via `startActivity()`, you are not immediately spawning that action. You are just kindly asking the framework to launch the specified activity for you. And it doesn't mean, that after `startActivity()` the code below it wouldn't be called. The executor will continue to execute the code until the end of scope. If you want to stop execution afterward you have to `return` immediately after `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, `catch (NullPointerException )` is always wrong. Plus `if (variable == null)` is arguably faster.

`AsyncTask` should just `return;` or stop, not necessarily start anything.

Another suggestion: Make sure that `doInBackground` returns an empty `JSONArray` instead of `null`.

> and the code below (for (int i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {}) still keeps running

Sure, because the for loop is not inside the `try` block...

```
try {
    result_length = result.length();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

    // Redirect the user back to the original activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(ResultActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// The result is still null here...
```

---

Replace all catching with a simpler null check and simply don't let the loop be entered.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

    int result_length = result == null ? 0 : result.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < result_length; i++) {
        // This loop won't run when the result is null... 
    }
```

If you really want to, then check `if (result_length == 0)`, but again, the Activity should be called back to when the result finishes, and **then** you can start some other activity.

Ref: [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)